# How to read nested Json using scala?

Tags: json, scala

I am using scala to separate json.
I have following Json structure-

```
"commands":{
"myinfo": [
    {
        "utilization": {
            "sizeBytes": 998848331776,
            "usedBytes": 408722341888,
            "freeBytes": 590125989888
        },
        "name": "ds1",
        "addons": [
            "PQR",
            "ABC"
        ],
        "otherInfo": {
            "model": "MRSASRoMB-4i",
            "name": "naa.6d867d9c7acd60001aed76eb2c70bd53",
            "vendor": "LSI"
        }
    }
]
}}
```

I want to read value of otherInfo, utilization etc.
I can read value of name using following code-

```
val commandInfo = (rawData \ "Commands").as[JsValue]
(commandInfo \ "myInfo").as[List[JsObject]].map { myJson =>
val name =  (myJson \  "name").asOpt[String]
}
```

I am using case classes in scala.
How do I get values of 'otherInfo','addons' etc using scala?

Comment: which library are you using in Scala for handling JSON? Looking at your code, perhaps you are using Play framework. Can you confirm and also checkout this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson

Answer (score 1):

Are you using dispatch's JSON support? If so, then you might want to consider using *json4s* instead, which is little like the de facto standard.

I personally would consider trying to use [SON of JSON](https://github.com/wspringer/sonofjson) instead, which would make getting the name out a breeze:

```
commands.myinfo.otherinfo.name.as[String]
```

… but then again, that's a shameless plug for something I wrote myself. ;-)